# Won't send all parameters to post http request

Tags: java, http, url, post, request

I am trying to send a http request with java. This is my code:

```
String AnnonseUrl = "http://webpage.no/insert_annonse.php?info="+info+"&tittel="+tittel+"&bedriftsNavn="+bedriftsNavn+"&kontaktEmail="+kontaktEmail+"&varighet="+varighet+"&frist="+frist+"&url="+url+"&sted="+sted+"&kontaktNavn="+kontaktNavn;            

            URL url = new URL(AnnonseUrl);
            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                    uc.getInputStream()));

            in.close();
```

Only the first three parameters are submitted..

If I copie the string "AnnonseUrl" and paste it in to my browser, then everything works fine.

Comment: What doesn't work? Why? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

When doing a post the parameters are send in the Http Body:
Try this:

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
              conn.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

Where urlParameters is something like:

```
 String urlParameters =
    "tittel="+URLEncoder.encode(tittel,"UTF-8")
    +"&bedriftsNavn"+URLEncoder.encode(bedriftsNavn,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: I get an error when I try this method..  [ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)]